# How to format/partition SD card?

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, sd-card

How can I format or partition SD card in Kubuntu? 
Is there an application with GUI for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would recommend installing [gnome-disk-utility](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-disk-utility) [image: Install gnome-disk-utility], which allows you to add / remove partitions, format the partitions with a given filesystem, and change the volume label. Of course, for an SD card, you'll probably just want to format it (using FAT if you need Windows compatibility or Ext2 otherwise).

I don't think this application ships with Kubuntu by default, but it should be available in the repos. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a similar utility for KDE as I am using Kubuntu?

Comment: @M.Sameer: You can install this program in Kubuntu.

Comment: Wouldn't this install many extra packages related to Genome?

Comment: @M.Sameer: It will if you don't have any other packages that depend on Gnome. But it won't be *that* many.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend installing gparted. It will let you manage partitions, as well as formatting and labelling the partitions using the file format of your choice. You can install it by entering:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Once installed, it will be made available under System -> Administration.

** Be careful about where you use GParted. It can be dangerous. **

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a similar utility for KDE as I am using Kubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

**(KDE) Partition Manger**

KDE-apps: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=89595

Ubuntu repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=partition+manager&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

apt-cache show partitionmanager is telling:

Description:

A partition management utility
 Partition Manager is a utility program to help you manage the disk devices,
 partitions and file systems on your computer. It allows you to easily create,
 copy, move, delete, resize without losing data, backup and restore partitions.
 .

Partition Manager supports a large number of file systems, including ext2/3/4,
 reiserfs, NTFS, FAT16/32, jfs, xfs and more. Note that to gain support for a
 specific file system other than ext2/3/4, you should install the corresponding
 suggested package.
 .

Partition Manager is based on libparted (like gparted) and makes use of the
 KDE libraries for its user interface.

Homepage: http://www.partitionmanager.org

Comment: In my experience, this only allows formatting by deleting and creating a new partition.

Comment: partition manager won't bring up SD cards (mmcblk-type devices) At least not on 14.04LTS Kubuntu