# Partitioning SD-Card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format/partition SD card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44557/how-to-format-partition-sd-card)

I want to partition SD-Card to use the [Link2SD](http://www.link2sd.info/) on android based mobile phone.
I should make two partitions.

- first a Fat partition for the user data
- second an ext4 for the applications

How can I do this?

Comment: This has been asker before: [How to format/partition SD card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44557/how-to-format-partition-sd-card)

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways of doing it. I am assuming that you have a card reader.

Start `gparted` and make the partitions.

You can do it from the terminal.

List all disks

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You need to figure out which disk is your card; it's usually something like `/dev/sdc`. I will use "xxx".

```
sudo fdisk /dev/xxx
```

Some `fdisk` commands:

- `d`: delete partition
- `n`: create a partition
- `l`: list types
- `t`: set type (c for fat32. 83 for Linux)
- `w`: save
- `q`: quit without making any changes

Then you create filesystems with a command:

```
sudo mkfs -t vfat -F 32 /dev/xxx1
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /def/xxx2
```

Comment: The direct and clean linux way. But I think `vfat -F` has a space before `32`