# Partitioning SD-Card gives an error: "Read-only file system"

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, sd-card

When I followed the link 
[Partitioning SD-Card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240497/partitioning-sd-card), I get the following error message:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: Read-only file system
```

I have given permissions for the media folder and the files inside it also. What can I do?

Comment: Are you running fdisk as root?

Comment: Is the drive formatted with an operating system?

Comment: Having permission to write to the filesystem on the SD card is not sufficient; you must use `sudo` or be `root` to partition a disk -- even a removable disk like an SD card. That's simply the way the permissions for partitioning work in Ubuntu.

Comment: There are several things to check/do, when a memory card appears to be read-only. You can often fix the problem, but it happens that the card is damaged beyond repair. See this link for more details, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the write-protect switch on the SD card is set, so the device is read-only.

This is the little slider on the side without the missing corner. It may be marked "Lock" or "Write Protect" or something similar.

If this is the case, disable the write protect switch and try again.